# Format specifier to print following data in C

Tags: c

Could someone help me in printing the following data in C, exact format specifier and procedure to print.

```
            union
            {
                            char       c[8];
                            short     s[4];
                            long       l[2];
                            void *    vfp[2];
            } info;
```

When i try using printf("%s\n", info.c); and printf("%s\n",info.s). I got some garbage values.
Also i need help in printing those pointers. 
Thanks for the support.

Comment: Your problem is the use of the union. You should use a `struct` instead if you intend on more than one being active at a time.

Comment: What is the desired output? You have 4 different representations of the same data. If this is a variant of some kind there should be an indicator of which element is valid.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand that the usage semantics of a **[union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#C.2FC.2B.2B)**. You can only read the *type* that you stored inside a particular object instance of union. And you can only store one type in a union at a particular instance in time.
So either you stored `s` or `c`, it cannot be both. If your intention is to store both the types then what you need is a structure and not a union.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're [using a union](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/c-difference-between-struct-and-union/).  the memory is *shared* between those 4 arrays.  I'm not sure you want that.

Second, the list of [format specifiers is here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).  `%s` is for strings.  `%p` is for pointers, and `%ld` can be used for a signed long.